# How to set combo's options/ Store dynamically

Tags: extjs4

I am using itscomponentcolumn in my Grid.

I want to set different store for every user.

If in a Grid there are 4 user's , I want to set for every user different combo store so that when user click on the Combo, he will see option's depending upon his permission, OR store that I will set.

```
xtype: 'itscomponentcolumn',
            text : '<b>Permission</b>',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'permission',
            items: function(value,record) {
            return { 
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: [[0,'View Only'], [1,'View & Edit'], [2,'View,Edit & Delete'],[3,'No Access']],
                //store:Combo_Store,
                queryMode:'local',
                displayField: 'display',
                valueField: 'value',
                name:'permission',
                forceSelection:true,
                width: 145,
                listeners: { }
```

I can not attached image. 
Just imagine there is Grid with 5 records.
Grid has 2 columns, user Name, Permission
in Permission column I am showing combo , for which code I gave above.

suppose there is vivek user , if he has view only permission's then i want to show view only in the combo just next to vivek record.

Same for other user's.

I have tried to set the store using bindStore, but didn't work for me.

Please suggest me how to do this ?

after your suggestion my code is like this

```
xtype: 'itscomponentcolumn',
            text : '<b>Permission</b>',
            width: 250,
            sortable:false,
            dataIndex: 'permission',
            items: function(value,record) {
            return { 
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: new Ext.data.Store({
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: comboStoreURL+"&currenetUserId="+record.get("userId"),
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'jsonStore'
                        }
                    },
                    autoLoad: true
                }),
```

But Can I know why to give call server each time? i mean for every record.I guess there must be some other way to do this because I have permission in my Grid's store.

My actual Grid code is like this.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', 
            {
                storeId: 'ShareComponentStoreId', 
                fields: ['userId','userName','permission','isProjectOwner'],
                 proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url:strURL,
                    reader: 
                    {
                        root: 'rootShareGrid', 
                        totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                    },
                    writer: 
                    {
                        type: 'json', 
                        writeAllFields: false, 
                        allowSingle: false, 
                        encode: true, 
                        root: 'row'
                    } 
                }

            }); 


var shareGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            id: 'ShareComponentGrId',
            enableColumnMove:false,
            store: store,
        columns: [
        {
            text: '<b>Name</b>',
            flex: 1,            
            sortable:false,
            width: 100,
            dataIndex: 'userName'
        },
        { 
            xtype: 'itscomponentcolumn',
            text : '<b>Permission</b>',
            width: 250,
            sortable:false,
            dataIndex: 'permission',
            items: function(value,record) {
            return { 
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: new Ext.data.Store({
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: comboStoreURL+"&currenetUserId="+record.get("userId"),
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'jsonStore'
                        }
                    },
                    autoLoad: true
                }),
                queryMode : 'local',
                displayField: 'display',
                valueField: 'value',
                name:'permission',
                forceSelection:true,
                width: 200,
```

So the record.get('permission') has that users permission.

I want to add that permission to the Combo store.

i.e. default combostore + the user's permission.

Hope I am able to explain well here.

Please reply me as early as possible on this

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this of course. 
What I would suggest is to have a Permissions store with autoLoad:true. You fetch user permissions right away and then it is available to your combobox when the grid loads.

Comment: Can you please show me the code to do this ? I have set the autoLoad:true , to my combo.

Comment: Define the store as separate class and set autoLoad:true. Populate the data from the server based on your user id. Then use that store with your combobox. The data will be there by the time you need to select something from the combo.  If this is not enough info please explain what is not working.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help I have done something like the one in my first post. Please review and let me know i am doing right or wrong. I have added new code after my comment "after your suggestion my code is like this" Please suggest me

Comment: don't create a new store instance for every record. define the store separately and refer to the store in your combo config. Use Ext.define('myStore',{extend:'Ext.data.Store',...} and the store:'myStore' makes sense?

Comment: ok , but in that case also there will separate query for the each record that is present in the Grid. 
My flow is like this, First Grid gets load, and it fetches the records from DB with all the permission for combo. Sencond I am populating Combo store somewhere else. I just want to save or copy permissoion from Grid's store to combo's store.
Is there any way to put permission from the Grid store to the Combo store ? as that will solve my problem and it also save one more hit to DB. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: i dont know what your data looks like - are you getting a permission array with every record? - do you need to? are your permissions row level or grid level ...